# Excel VBA hlookup function

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use the excel VBA HLookup function. I have tried it two ways and both produce error. Could anyone explain me what is that I am doing wrong?

First try:

```
    lookupValue = Worksheets(1).Name & "!A1"
    tableArray = Worksheets(3).Name & "!$A$1:$" & Col_letter & "$1"
    Worksheets("Comparison").Cells(1, 2).Value = "=HLookup(" & lookupValue _
    & ";" & tableArray & ";1;FALSE)"
```

Second try:

```
    tda = Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value ' I also tried using tda without .Value
    Table = Worksheets(3).Range(Cells(1, 1))
    Worksheets("Comparison").Cells(1, 2).Value = WorksheetFunction. _
    HLookup(tda, Table, 1, False)
```

Comment: What is the error?  On what line does it occur?  What is the nature of lookup_value and the data in table_array?  In your first try, if you want to write the **results** of the formula, you need to `Evaluate`.  If you want to use the formula, you should use the `.Formula` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first one, you need to use US regional settings, so a comma separator, and you should really enclose the sheet names in single quotes in case they contain spaces or look like special names (e.g. dates):

```
lookupValue = "'" & Worksheets(1).Name & "'!A1"
tableArray = "'" & Worksheets(3).Name & "'!$A$1:$" & Col_letter & "$1"
Worksheets("Comparison").Cells(1, 2).Formula = "=HLookup(" & lookupValue _
& "," & tableArray & ",1,FALSE)"
```

and for the second you have to use a range object for the table argument:

```
tda = Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value ' I also tried using tda without .Value
Set Table = Worksheets(3).Range(Worksheets(3).Cells(1, 1), Worksheets(3).Cells(1, Col_letter))
Worksheets("Comparison").Cells(1, 2).Value = WorksheetFunction. _
HLookup(tda, Table, 1, False)
```

I have assumed Table is declared as Variant, Object or Range.

Note you will still get a run-time error if there is no match for your lookup value.

Comment: Thank you! i used the second one. For the first one I assumed that it has to look as if I type it in Excel sheet, since there semicolon is required I used the semicolon in VBA as well.

Comment: How can I skip the run-time error if the values do not match?

Comment: It depends what you want to happen but basically you either need an `On Error` statement  of some sort, or you can use `Application.HLookup` instead which will return an error value rather than raising a run-time error. You can assign the result of the function to a `Variant` variable and then test that using `IsError` and decide what to do.

Answer (score 1):

what you're doing there usually works, which is creating a string with the function you want to call and inputting it.

I don't think that's the safest way, since it would not work if you run that macro from an Excel with a different language.

the proper way to call an Excel function from VBA call is for example:

```
cells(1,2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(123,Range("A1:C100"),3,FALSE)
```

anyway if you'd rather use this string approach the problem in the first try is that

```
"=HLookup(" & lookupValue _
    & ";" & tableArray & ";1;FALSE)"
```

results in the string:

```
=HLookup(Sheet1!A1;Sheet3!$A$1:$B$1;1;FALSE)
```

note that you're using semicolons  where you're supposed to use commmas.

the problem in the second try is that the `.Range` property takes a string as input, so you cant `Range(Cells(1,1))` you should do something like `.Range("A1:A3")`

hope it helps !